# Get lowest price based on maximum timestamp - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get lowest price based on maximum timestamp. I've tableid only to get the date out of table.

My query should be something like:

```
SELECT min(price) as price, timestamp, resellerid, tableid
        FROM `sql_date_table`
        WHERE tableid=%d
        AND max(timestamp)
```

Any time will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Example data

```
tableid | resellerid | price   | timestamp
-----------------------------------------
4           1          1549900   1516405599
4           1          2097042   1518618827
4           1          2107168   1519739181
4           2          1649900   1515352455
4           2          1649900   1518618508
4           2          1649900   1519739180
4           3          1700000   1520962427
4           3          1649900   1519828070
6           2          299400    1519738727
6           3          188800    1520962413
8           1          249900    1518618488
8           2          249500    1518618509
```

**The idea is to get "latest crawled" lowest price**

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: @dfundako  `AND max(timestamp)` isn't possible to use as valid syntax

Comment: What is your expected output based on the test data provided?

Comment: @kc2018 It should be **1649900** since its the lowest price with latest timestamp.

Comment: Are you trying to find the lowest price among the various resellers based on their latest price?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Are you maybe looking at the maximum timestamp per tableid + resellerid (lines 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12 in your example)? And from those records you want the minimum price? Or is it the maximum timestamp per tableid only (lines 7, 10, 12 in your example)? And from these the minimum price? Or still something else?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you might want:

```
select t.*
from t
where tableid = ?
order by timestamp desc, price asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying quickly. I tested it. It shows price having latest timestamp but price isn't lowest. I was looking for **lowest price having latest timestamp**. Sometimes timestamp can be latest with higher price fetched so we wont need that higher price.

Comment: @wpstudent . . . Your sample data has no duplicate timestamps.  Hence this returns the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `sql_date_table` WHERE `timestamp`
    IN (SELECT min(`timestamp`) FROM `sql_date_table`
        WHERE `tableid` = ? ORDER BY `price` DESC) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tested. it returns zero sized array

Comment: @wpstudent What is the data type of `timestamp` column?

Comment: `int(11) NOT NULL` and btw you missed supplying `tableid` criteria in query

Comment: Query works just fine. It returns `price = 1549900` according to your table in the question.

Comment: Sorry If I failed to explain earlier. It should be **1649900** since its the lowest price with latest timestamp

Comment: ohh.. just change the values. check now. it returns `price = 1649900`

Comment: Thanks that was quick :) but if I may ask. Why didn't you added `tableid` in query. Its mandatory to consider. There are multiple records associated with **unique tableid**

and sorry I didn't supplied multiple tableid in sample data, that might have confused you

Comment: `tableId` doesn't matter in this case. Our main priority is to get the latest crawled lowest price... Moreover if the `tableId` is [**unique**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+unique) how can it have multiple records??

Comment: `tableId` isn't unique. The only available parameter to get price from database is `tableId`. The current query you suggest is a general one. But thanks anyway I'll try refining it.

Comment: According to the updated data table, you should add the `tableid` as a condition, **it is important**. Sorry my mistake. Check the updated answer. You are welcome...

Answer (score 1):

This returns the lowest price from the *latest price quotes per reseller*:

```
SELECT Min(price)
FROM tab AS t1
JOIN
 (
   SELECT resellerid, Max(timestamp) AS max_ts
   FROM tab 
   GROUP BY resellerid
 ) AS t2
ON t1.timestamp = t2.max_ts
```

As your question is unclear you might want/need to add `tableid` to the GROUP BY.

If you want additional colums:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab AS t1
JOIN
 (
   SELECT resellerid, Max(timestamp) AS max_ts
   FROM tab 
   GROUP BY resellerid
 ) AS t2
ON t1.timestamp_ = t2.max_ts
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1
```

When there are multiple resellers with the same price this will return one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Max timestamp will have multiple occurrence? Use group by with MIN() will resolve your issue if this is the problem.

Comment: The idea is to get "latest crawled" lowest price

Answer (score 0):

To find the lowest price among the resellers based on their latest price:

```
select resellerid, price, timestamp
from sql_date_table
where 
tableid = ?
and
timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
                   from sql_date_table t2
                   where t2.tableid = sql_date_table.tableid
                   and   t2.resellerid = sql_date_table.resellerid)
order by price limit 1;
```

OR

```
select resellerid, price, timestamp
from sql_date_table
where 
tableid = 4
and
timestamp = (select timestamp
                   from sql_date_table t2
                   where t2.tableid = sql_date_table.tableid
                   and   t2.resellerid = sql_date_table.resellerid
                   order by timestamp desc limit 1)
order by price limit 1
```